# Tell mstest to ignore test methods in a base class but not in subclasses

Tags: java, c++, .net, abstract

I have a base test class that has a method(say **ABC**()), and one property (Say **Prop1**) that need to be implemented by the child classes, if not implemented by child class then it throws "Not Implemented" exception -- It is fine.

I have marked this ABC() method as [TestMethod].

Now this method to be executed only by the child classes derived from this but not from the base class class itself. i.e. this method should execute only for the child classes not for the base class itself.

**What actually the problem is..**

How could i ensure that this method should not execute from the base class??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That sounds like a very odd design for a test to start with. Can you explain the design decision? It may be that a different approach would be better - such as making your base class abstract to start with.

Comment: Well if the object is the type of the child class then it will use the child method and property if they override the parent (by default of course). but why even have a parent and a child if the parent is going to be just full of `not implemented exceptions`. why not just have one class? Also you specify `java`, `C++` and `.net` so it will differ between different languages.

Comment: Nicolas Tyler: Its in C#.Net

Comment: Hi Jon:The design is like-  I have a common method that need to be executed for many classes. for that i have made 1 base class that has implemented this common method and all child classes are derived from this base class n create their own test methods. now to ensure that all the child classes derived from this base class, I have placed one required Property inside base class that need to be implemented in child classes.

Comment: Jon: I tried to make this bases class and common property as abstract but in that case the base test method gets execute only from child classes but not from the base class as it becomes "Not executable" from base class...  Hope we are making sense to each other. :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you need to make ABC() a pure virtual function:

```
virtual void ABC() = 0;
```